# javascript @ JQuery : ajax call in a "success" method of an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The problem is that with the setInterval code(see below), the page has a bug. Without it(setInterval and its function inside), it works.
Do you know if the second ajax call is valid, inside of the success function of a first ajax call?

here is my code :(the goal is to see if a thread is launched; if it is launched it clear the datatable, otherwise it reload it with an ajax call(which is working by the way); if the thread is not launched, I would expect it to call the server each 500ms until the thread has ended.)

```
function seeIfOccupied() {
        $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : 'occupe/1',
                    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        //window.alert(data);
                        //non=pas de thread lancé
                        if (data == "non" && jQuery('#from').val() != ""
                                && jQuery('#from').val() != "") {
                            firstTable.fnReloadAjax("json/" + $("#from").val()
                                    + "/" + $("#to").val());
                        } else {
                            alert("Pas de récupération de la table.Les dates sont peut-être vides\nou le traitement horaire est lancé");

                            if (firstTable != undefined) {
                                firstTable.each(function() {
                                    firstTable.fnDeleteRow(0);
                                });
                            };
                            //MAJ de l'affichage de la durée du job
                            setInterval( function () {
                                //appel ajax
                                $.ajax({
                                    type : 'GET',
                                    url : 'occupe2/2',
                                    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                        $.("#occupe").html(data);

                                    },//success function
                                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        window.alert(textStatus);
                                    };
                                });//$.ajax
                            },500);//setInterval
                        }//else
                    },//success function
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        window.alert(textStatus);
                    }

        });//$.ajax
    };//seeIfOccupied
```

thanks for your replies.
with this code it also doesn't work:

```
function seeIfOccupied() {
        $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : 'occupe/1',
                    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        //window.alert(data);
                        //non=pas de thread lancé
                        if (data == "non" && jQuery('#from').val() != ""
                                && jQuery('#to').val() != "") {
                            firstTable.fnReloadAjax("json/" + $("#from").val()
                                    + "/" + $("#to").val());
                        } else {
                            alert("Pas de récupération de la table.Les dates sont peut-être vides\nou le traitement horaire est lancé");
                            if (firstTable != undefined) {
                                firstTable.each(function() {
                                    firstTable.fnDeleteRow(0);
                                });
                            };
                            //MAJ de l'affichage de la durée du job
                            setInterval( function () {
                                //appel ajax
                                $.ajax({
                                    type : 'GET',
                                    url : 'occupe2/2',
                                    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                        $.("#occupe").html(data);

                                    },//success function
                                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                        window.alert(textStatus);
                                    }//error function
                                })//$.ajax
                            },500);//setInterval
                        }//else
                    },//success function
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        window.alert(textStatus);
                    }

        });//$.ajax
    };//seeIfOccupied
```

Comment: Why are you checking JQuery('#from').val() twice in your if?

Comment: @Nate:you're right, there are 2 fields I wanted to test : #from, & #to. Dring all my changes I made this error(but it's not blocking the page althought)

Comment: "the page has a bug" doesn't convey much information... JS throws an error? Site's behaviour is unexpected? Is it a syntax "bug"? If not then when it occurs?

Comment: ok : the page has a bug means : I have 2 datepickers (jquery components) and a datatable (again a jquery component) whose behavious is altered : the datepickers don't display the month's window, and the datatable does not display its search box.

Comment: ok, it's nearly solved : I had an error message complaining about $.("#occupe"); I changed it to jQuery("#occupe").html... and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'occupe2/2',

    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $.("#occupe").html(data);
    },

    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.alert(textStatus);
    }; //<----- This pointcomma should be a comma
});



error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    window.alert(textStatus);
}, //<----- This is right
```

Comment: Actually, since it's the final option, you just leave away the comma because it is not needed. I don't know if the javascript parser would break on a comma there, but it's not even needed.

Comment: Yup, it's not needed, but it's better to include it, just for don't forget to type it if you expand the object.